# Assumptions for the exponential law for pointed spaces

Tags: general-topology

We have a set map
$$\theta_*:Map_*(X\wedge Y,B)\to Map_*(Y,Map_*(X, B))$$
where the mapping space $Map_*$
for based spaces is the subspace of the usual mapping space, in the compact-open topology, which consists of the mappings preserving the base point.

In Dieck's Algebraic Topology (Theorem 2.4.11.) it is claimed that if $X$ and $Y$ are locally compact (have a base of compact neighborhoods), then this map is a homeomorphism. I tried arguing like for the non pointed case, so to argue that $\theta_*$ is continuous, I need to check that the induced map
$$\theta_*:(Map_*(X\wedge Y,B)\wedge Y) \wedge X \to B$$
This clearly holds if associativity of the smash product holds, but this doesn't happen in general. A sufficient condition would be that $Map_*(X\wedge Y,B)$ is locally compact. I haven't been able to show this last result (I know that if $X$ and $Y$ are locally compact then so is $X \wedge Y$).

Is this last result true? If not, how can the argument be fixed?

Comment: Where in the book is this claim?

Comment: @Thorgott My bad, it is theorem 2.4.11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the natural thing to do cause we are working in the pointed category, but nothing forces us to use the pointed adjunction. The map
$$\mathrm{Map}_{\ast}(X\wedge Y,B)\rightarrow\mathrm{Map}_{\ast}(X,\mathrm{Map}_{\ast}(Y,B))\subseteq\mathrm{Map}(X,\mathrm{Map}_{\ast}(Y,B))$$
is continuous iff the adjoint $\mathrm{Map}_{\ast}(X\wedge Y,B)\times X\rightarrow\mathrm{Map}_{\ast}(Y,B)\subseteq\mathrm{Map}(Y,B)$ is continuous, which in turn is continuous iff the adjoint $\mathrm{Map}_{\ast}(X\wedge Y,B)\times X\times Y\rightarrow B$ is continuous (no associativity problems here). This map is continuous, because it is the composite of the map $\mathrm{Map}_{\ast}(X\wedge Y,B)\rightarrow\mathrm{Map}_{\ast}(X\times Y,B)$ that is the pullback along the canonical projection $X\times Y\rightarrow X\wedge Y$ and the evaluation map $\mathrm{Map}_{\ast}(X\times Y,B)\times X\times Y\rightarrow B$, which is continuous because $X$ and $Y$, hence $X\times Y$, are locally compact. The inverse similarly requires you to mix the smash and cartesian product.